# How to build API call volume-based charging model

Tags: node.js, api, strongloop, loopbackjs

I' looking into loopback.io for node API management. What I'm still unclear about is how to precisely monitor API calls per user/API key and connect a solution to a volume-based plan, e.g. "1 mio API calls/month free, then 0.01$ per 1000 calls". 
Anybody done this before and can recommend some practices/ well-fitting payment provider?
Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires API metering, which is on our roadmap but not available yet. However we have one user  who has implemented this using metrics for rate limiting. If you need more details do send us an email at callback[at]strongloop.com